# Subject Region Estimation using OpenImaj Library

Tags: java, image-processing

I came across functions in the [OpenImaj library](http://openimaj.org/apidocs/org/openimaj/image/saliency/AchantaSaliency.html)  (LuoTangSubjectRegion and Achanta Saliency) that I would love to use them , however the problem is that Java is far from my first language. Therefore I wanted to ask if somebody could help me with trying to implement a simple piece of code that would read in an image, compute its saliency map and save that saliency map?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample.  I am not sure it works, but i suspect it is closer than what you have.

I am not a maven expert.  Apparently, you need maven to download the library.  http://openimaj.org/UseLibrary.html.  Sadly, this means I can't test this sample.

Good luck, for more code samples see http://openimaj.org/tutorial/processing-your-first-image.html.

```
import org.openimaj.image.MBFImage;
import org.openimaj.image.FImage;
        //You will need several more imports.  Your IDE can handle that.
public class SampleImage {
    public static Main(String args[])
    {
        //Read image in
        MBFImage image = ImageUtilities.readMBF(new File("c:\\file.jpg"));

        //Print out random information
        System.out.println(image.colourSpace);

        //Create Object to preform work.
        AchantaSaliency test = new AchantaSaliency();

        //Get Saliency Map
        test.analyseImage(image);
        FImage newImage = test.getSaliencyMap();

        //Display original image
        DisplayUtilities.displayImage(image);

        //Display new image
        DisplayUtilities.displayImage(newImage);

        //Save new image to file
        ImageUtilities.write(newImage, new File("C:\\test_output.jpg"));

    }    

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate it. Will try it and ask more questions in anything comes up. Really appreciate it!

Comment: I updated the answer slightly.  Writes newImage now, not image, to file.